# q1.classList.add("isHidden"); The function works, but after some seconds the page reloads and goes back to notHidden

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

My index.js file

```
var q1 = document.getElementById('q1')
var q2 = document.getElementById('q2')

s1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    q1.classList.add("isHidden");
    q2.classList.remove("isHidden");
})
```

So, whenever I click the s1 button, q1 gets "isHidden", now display: none , q2 removes "isHidden", now display: block.
But, after like a second or two, the page, kinda reloads, and they go back to normal, q1 display: "block" and q2 display: "none".

Comment: Are you reloading the page or is it reloading automatically? If it is reloading automatically then something else is responsible for reloading the page and you need to investigate in that direction

Comment: Something else is reloading the page, i wish i could show u a video.
I click the button, it changes the question, by hiding the first one and showing the second one, but than it loads back to the first one

Comment: wait i think i just solved it
idk why but changing the button <button></button> to <a></a> made it work